# Young tableaux to Specht polynomial to Irreducible representation for $(1,3,5) \in S_5$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

**What I am trying to do?**

Work out the irreducible representation of the group element $(1,3,5) \in S_5$ for the partition $2+2+1$ .

**Motivation:**

Learn how to calculate irreducible representation from Young tableaux.

**Group:** $S_5$

**Partitions and Young tableaux:**

[image]

**Now I pick the partition $2+2+1$ and work out the representation of the group element $(1,3,5) \in S_5$.**

First I work out the standard Young tableaux for the shape $2+2+1$.

[image]

Now I compute the Specht polynomials for each of the tableau.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I compute the representation for the permutation $\left(1, 3, 5\right) \in S_5$.

[image]

[image]

So, the irreducible representation of $\left(1, 3, 5\right)$ is :

[image]

**My question:**
Am I doing it right?